# Java: addToDay function

Tags: java, function, date

I'm trying to setup my addToDay function. I'm currently stuck on how to proceed with this or even write it correctly. The function itself will take a variable that ranges from -100 to 100. So you would basically add that variable to the current and if it was below the 0 then subtract a month or if it was above the months max day then add a month. Which i have that function setup so all i would have to do is call addToMonth with the correct amount. My problem lies within the amount of days each month has. For example, October has 31 days while November has 30. I have a function that will return the number of days in the current set month so i can call that to get how many max days should be in the current month. I'm thinking maybe a while loop would work but i just wanted to get anyone's thoughts on the best way to set it up.

I have 3 private ints: month, day, year. These are what need to be changed. I have both addTo functions for month and year setup already.

Here are some other functions i have created that can be used in this:
1. addToMonth(int delta) - changes the current month depending on the given parameter
2. getDaysInMonth() - will return the days in a month depending on the month itself
3. validateDay() - Will return true or false if the days fall outside the wanted requirements.

*I don't want to use the calendar utility*

*I also don't want to use any other utilities. Just the base code with Junit for testing*

Comment: OK, what data type are you using to store your days?  (The best one is probably `LocalDate` from the `java.time` package if I understand your requirements correctly).

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry should've said this originally and i will edit it into the original question. All this is self sustaining and i do not want to use anything outside of the pure base code. I currently have 3 private int variables: year, day, and month. I am currently only using JUnit to test everything.

Comment: The java.time classes are built into Java 8 and later. Date-time is deceptively tricky stuff; do not reinvent this wheel. `YearMonth.from( LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).plusMonths( 3 ) ).getLengthOfMonth()`

Comment: Not really wanting to reinvent it, but sadly i can't use any outside librarys. i'm trying to get this assignment done and this is legit the only thing preventing me from turning it in.

Answer (score 0):

Joda's [plusDays()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays(int)) function and Java 8 [LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-)  already has the logic that you are trying to achieve

Comment: I basically want to recreate Joda's function. I want to do all this within the base code by hand without having to call an outside function.

Comment: I usually disapprove duplicated efforts <- (rant). Having expressed that, have you take a peek to [Joda's logic](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTime.java)?, it may give you some inspiration for your quest.

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode with the team advising migration to the java.time classes. The java.time source code is available in the OpenJDK project but beware the GPL license.

Comment: I fully agree with the rant. I'll check out the logic and return with hopefully a completed function and a check for you.

Comment: Sadly i didn't find anything that would really benefit me in my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i ended up just copying my original addToMonth function and modifying it abit to fit with days. So far it works but i do think it'll fail in the cases of different amounth of days not lining up.